# Why does the flow direction tool in ArcGIS desktop give wrong output (unique values from 1-255)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, hydrology, flow

I ran the flow direction in ArcGIS, and received unique values ranging from 1-255. I know that these values are wrong, and should be along the lines of 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc multiples. The DEM is projected. What could cause this? [image: The is the output of the flow direction. The red point refers to the outlet point.]

Comment: To get correct numbers you have to fill original DEM 1st

Comment: See what [the help page](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Flow_Direction) says about undefined directions and sinks.